# Vectorized solution to random sampling for each row in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I would like to translate for following for loop into vectorized format:

```
for (i in 1:100){ if (runif<0.01){b<-sample(1:2,1)} else {b<-NA}}
```

I was thinking of the following solution:

```
ifelse(runif(100,0,1)<prob_rand, sample(1:no_options,1),NA)
```

However the problem here is that sample is only executed once, so whenever the if condition is satisfied the same sample is assigned instead of a random sample for each of the 100 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example doesn't work, I imagine you meant:

```
for (i in 1:100){ if (runif<0.01){b<-sample(1:2,1)} else {b<-NA}}
```

To make the second part work, instead of running `sample` once, just run it `i` times.

```
no_options<-2
prob_rand<-0.5 # 0.01 is too low to verify that it is working.
ifelse(runif(100,0,1)<prob_rand, sample(1:no_options,100,replace=TRUE),NA)

#  [1] NA NA NA NA NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA  1  1 NA  1  2  2  2  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  2
# [26] NA  1 NA  1  2 NA NA NA  2 NA  2  1 NA  2  2  2 NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA  2 NA
# [51]  2 NA NA  2  1  1  1  2 NA  1 NA  1 NA  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA  2 NA NA
# [76]  1  1 NA  2 NA NA NA NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  2  1  1  1 NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  1
```

Comment: and is it possible to assign instead of NA nothing? so if there is already a value there then just keep that value?

Comment: It is hard for me to figure out what you mean. But I guess that you mean that some vector `b` already exists, and you want to replace values within it if the dice roll is greater than `prob_rand`, but if not, then just leave `b` alone. If that is the case, then just replace `NA` with `b`.

Answer (score 1):

How about making the sample vector first, then subsetting based on `prob_rand`...

```
x <- sample( 1:no_options , 100 , repl = TRUE )
x[ runif(100) > prob_rand ] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

In a data.frame may be ?

```
df = data.frame(r=runif(100))
df$b = ifelse(df$r<0.01,sample(1:2,1),NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use rbinom as well

```
n <- 100
(runif(n) < 0.1) * sample(2, n, replace = TRUE)
rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.1) * sample(2, n, replace = TRUE)
```

This will give 0, 1, 2 instead of NA, 1, 2.